# Having trouble figuring out how to resolve memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

This is my first attempt at fixing memory leaks for the first app that I've built. When I use the Leaks instrument, I get 1 leak on my Login View Controller and from what I can understand, it has something to do with AudioToolBox (AVFoundation) which I'm using for my looping video background.

So I thought I would try to set the `AVPlayer` variable to `weak`, but that did nothing for the leak.

How can I properly fix this leak?

Here is the code as it relates to the looping background video...

```
           weak var player : AVPlayer?
           weak var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer?


         override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()

              playBackgroundVideo()
          }



         func playBackgroundVideo() {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dumbbells2480", ofType: "mov") else { return }
            player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            player!.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer!.frame = self.view.frame
            playerLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            self.view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, at: 0)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player!.currentItem)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(playItem),name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
            
            player!.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            player!.play()
            self.player?.isMuted = true
            
            view.bringSubviewToFront(authStackView)
        }
        
        @objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(){
            player!.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        }
        
        @objc private func playItem() {
            playerItemDidReachEnd()
            player?.play()
            
            if let playerlayer = playerLayer {
                view.layer.insertSublayer(playerlayer, at: 0)
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You're worried because you leaked 16 bytes once?

Comment: ‍♂️ sorry I don't really know what I should or should not be worrying about. I was under the impression that just about any leak needs to be resolved, but please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm a very much a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is this leak less than trivial (16 bytes once, so tiny it can't be made out under a strong microscope) but there is no evidence from the Instruments display you've shown that it has anything to do with your code. Best strategy: move on.